# Android notification center pauses Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Does the "notification center", when moving with finger down, stop the activity and place the activity `onPause()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174279/notification-restart-my-activity-and-pause-button-on-notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your activity keeps running since the Notification Area is just an Overlay.